# "Include other layout" how change text dynamically?

Tags: android, layout, include, abstract-class

i have 10 layout and each layout is build with a title + subtitle same for all so i did:

```
public abstract class Menu_Segnalazione extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String titolo = intent.getStringExtra("titolo");
    final String sottoT = intent.getStringExtra("sottoT");

    //Display back arrow on actionbar
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.intestazione);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.titolo)).setText("ahh");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.sottoTitolo)).setText("xcvxcv");
}
```

and:

```
public class ActivityPalinePensiline extends Menu_Segnalazione {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.anomalia_paline);

    palineAction();

}
```

R.layout.anomalia_palina is the layout that have menu_segnalazione+other things
menu_segnalazione is the layout title + subtitle

the problem is that the text in R.id.titolo and R.id.sottoTitolo don't change....

what is wrong?

Comment: Post the contents of `R.layout.intestazione` for me please. And if you don't accept your previous questions, you're unlikely to get good answers, consider it

Comment: sometime the solution is write as comment at my post.. and i can't "accept" them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View initialisation you're doing on `Menu_Segnalazione::onCreate` is done but in the `ActivityPalinePensiline::onCreate` you're overriding this by loading a new layout just after the parent::onCreate ..

You should externalize your title/subtitle initialisation code in a `initView()` that you call in every `onCreate()` after the `setContentView()` method

Example :

```
public abstract class Menu_Segnalazione extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

protected void initViews() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String titolo = intent.getStringExtra("titolo");
    final String sottoT = intent.getStringExtra("sottoT");

    //Display back arrow on actionbar
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.intestazione);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.titolo)).setText("ahh");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.sottoTitolo)).setText("xcvxcv");
}
```

and

```
public class ActivityPalinePensiline extends Menu_Segnalazione {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.anomalia_paline);

    initViews();

    palineAction();

}

@Override
protected void initViews() {
   super.initViews();

   // add here custom initialisation for this activity
}
```

Comment: eheh i was editing my question with the solution..but you did the full example :) yeah all work now ty